# How to Get List Values From Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, list, splistitem

I am looking for a way to get list values from SharePoint 2007. Right now I am using PowerShell, and have the following script:

```
#load Microsoft.SharePoint.dll
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$12HivesDir\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll")
#returns the SPSite object from the specified URL
function get-spweb ([String]$webUrl=$(throw 'Parameter -webUrl is missing!'))
{
   $site =  New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite" -ArgumentList "$webUrl";
   return $site.OpenWeb();
}

$web = get-spweb http://myURL
$myList = $web.Lists["ListName"]

foreach($item in $myList.Items)
{
    $item.Title
    foreach($field in $item.Fields)
    {
        $field.Title
    }
}
```

This script prints out the column headers, but I need to get the actual values. What is the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($item in $myList.Items)
{
    $item.Title
    foreach($field in $item.Fields)
    {
        $item[$field.Title]
    }
}
```

This uses the title as the index of the list item in a dynamic manner. Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't you need to Write-Host or something as well? Or was that code just omitted?

Comment: Thanks for the help rjcup. Write-Host is not necessary. The way the script is written it will still output the values in Powershell. Also, without Write-Host, I am able to use output redirection to a file.